# MFC EditControl's value is not coming in private member

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog box with static text and edit control. In dialog control class, I have a control variable which to set initial value in edit box and a int which will have value of edit box when user changes it. Both are private variable but I am not getting values in integer variable. Is there any way to detect this below is sample code base

```
class CYrdAuthorityPage : public CPropertyPage
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CYrdAuthorityPage)

public:
    CYrdAuthorityPage();
    virtual ~CYrdAuthorityPage();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_YRD_AUTHORITY_DIALOG };


protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
private:
    CEdit m_authctrl;
    int m_authval;
public:
    afx_msg void OnEnChangeAuthEdit();

};

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CYrdAuthorityPage, CPropertyPage)

CYrdAuthorityPage::CYrdAuthorityPage()
    : CPropertyPage(CYrdAuthorityPage::IDD)
{

}

CYrdAuthorityPage::~CYrdAuthorityPage()
{
}

void CYrdAuthorityPage::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CPropertyPage::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_AUTH_EDIT, m_authctrl);
    DDX_Text(pDX,IDC_AUTH_EDIT,m_authval);
}


/*BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CYrdAuthorityPage, CPropertyPage)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_AUTH_EDIT, &CYrdAuthorityPage::OnEnChangeAuthEdit)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()*/
```

Here m_authval is not having value. I   think it could be because it's private but making it public also gives the same result. I have set edit box to align text centrally.

Thanks

Comment: [Dialog Data Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwz5tb1x.aspx)

Comment: Are you talking about an initial value?  You don't provide an initial value.

Comment: I have just given code snippets some of the details i removed as code is more than 600 lines long. But the problem is the same I don't get value using DDX macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data exchange between the control and the int variable does not occur magically. It occurs when you call the UpdateData member function. Do you have calls to that function?